# Jssor slider....can transition effects be use/applied when navigator buttons are clicked?

Tags: jquery, jssor

The transition effects in jssor can be used when auto playing the slider. I'm wondering if the slide transition effect can be used/triggered/applied when a bullet button is clicked in the navigator.

I'm basically looking to have the slider "fade" the images in the slider instead of "sliding" the images when the bullets are clicked in the navigator.

Answer (score 0):

i wonder too,vote.
look the code:

```
_SelfSlideItem.$GoForNextSlide = function () {
            if (_SlideshowRunner) {
                var slideshowTransition = _SlideshowRunner.$GetTransition(_SlideCount);

                if (slideshowTransition) {
                    var loadingTicket = _LoadingTicket = $JssorUtils$.$GetNow();

                    var nextIndex = slideIndex + 1 * _PlayReverse;
                    var nextItem = _SlideItems[GetRealIndex(nextIndex)];
                    return nextItem.$LoadImage($JssorUtils$.$CreateCallback(null, LoadSlideshowImageCompleteEventHandler, nextIndex, nextItem, slideshowTransition, loadingTicket), _LoadingScreen);
                }
            }

            PlayTo(_CurrentSlideIndex + _Options.$AutoPlaySteps * _PlayReverse);
        };
```